# How having equal to count(*) works?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g, having

I hope this image is saying enough about the rational table.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Student
```

Is returning number of students

and I am not sure what is this statement does.

```
SELECT c#
FROM Enrolment
GROUP BY c#
HAVING count(*) = ???
```

this has been group by c#. So count(*) must return number of students enrolled in each course. Therefore `HAVING count(*) = ???` must not defined to check if two values are equal! I appreciate if anyone can explain the role of `having` here?

**Added edit**

1. Is result of this select in the third select clause a constant value? Let's call it `A = 255` (assumption for number of students)

   ```
   SELECT c#
   FROM Enrolment
   GROUP BY c#
   HAVING count(*) =
                        (SELECT count(*) 
                         FROM Student)
   ```

My question exactly is in second select, `having count(*) = (count* in another select)` 
Is it comparing value of occurrence of C# (course number) in second select with  value of occurrence of S# (student number) in third select or it is like a for loop comparing different values of C# (course number) in the second select with value of number of student? My confusion is mainly with having condition! does that mean if

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to get? a list of students and their class titles?

Comment: @BadrGhatasheh I believe the goal is to get only those courses (course titles) which are taken by ALL students.  It would explain the (in my opinion) odd construct of `having count(*) = (select count(*) from student)`

Comment: That makes more sense than my assumption

Comment: My goal is to find out what is having statement is comparing in second select clause? As @CoolWilly said I know it is an odd construct of having but specifically what is comparing here?

Comment: @BadrGhatasheh Please have a look at edited part in my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c#
    FROM Enrolment
    GROUP BY c#
    HAVING count(*) = ???
```

You will select all `C#` as seen in comparison with the amount of times `C#` is in your records. With the having clause you can say that you are only interested in the `C#` values which have certain value.

So in this exact case your having clause will filter your results (courses) to include only those courses which have enrolled all students.

I hope this was the answer you were looking for.

Comment: C# is course number (weird way to say number as #) and S# is student number/id... So you mean having condition means, it is finding which course or courses, are enrolled by all students. It means %100 of students are enrolled in one course?